# Why Text doesn't render in the body before navigation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-text

For some reason, Text Widget doesn't work in my new view

I have a named navigation from the MaterialApp:

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>
'/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
'/recipes': (BuildContext context) => const Recetas(),
```

Everything is good in the home page, but the Text Widget doesn't render any text in my App

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:naturale_app/constraits.dart';

class Recetas extends StatelessWidget {
  const Recetas({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        title: const Text("Recetas"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kWhiteColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: const Text( // This doesn't Render
            "Recetas",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: kBlackColor,
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this: [Recetas Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8RsE.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be your text color issue, both background and text having the same color, check your `kBlackColor` color.

```dart
 child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kWhiteColor, //here 
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: const Text( 
            "Recetas",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: kBlackColor, //and here the same as bg on color decleration,
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Change the text color to black or something

```dart
style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
```